# What's the propper way to insert data one to many relation symfony4?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

It's simple im doing a permission table from Companies and Users where i have to store the user id and the company id right now i have this and i get this error

> Expected value of type "App\Entity\CompanyUserPermissionMap" for association field "App\Entity\User#$companyUserPermissionMaps", got "App\Entity\Company" instead.

User Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $userId;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=12)
 */
private $code;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
 */
private $email;


/**
 * @var CompanyUserPermissionMap[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CompanyUserPermissionMap", mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $companyUserPermissionMaps;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->companyUserPermissionMaps = new ArrayCollection();
}


public function getCompanyUserPermissionMaps(): Collection
{
    return $this->companyUserPermissionMaps;
}

public function addCompanyUserPermissionMaps(CompanyUserPermissionMaps $permission): self
{
    if (!$this->companyUserPermissionMaps->contains($permission)) {
        $this->companyUserPermissionMaps[] = $permission;
        $permission->setUser($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Company Entity

```
#########################
##      PROPERTIES     ##
#########################

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $companyId;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=6, unique=true)
 */
private $code;



/**
 * @var CompanyUserPermissionMap[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CompanyUserPermissionMap", mappedBy="company", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $companyUserPermissionMaps;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->companyUserPermissionMaps = new ArrayCollection();

}



/**
 * @return Collection|CompanyUserPermissionMaps[]
 */
public function getCompanyUserPermissionMaps(): Collection
{
    return $this->companyUserPermissionMaps;
}

public function addCompanyUserPermissionMaps(AccountingBankPermission $permission): self
{
    if (!$this->companyUserPermissionMaps->contains($permission)) {
        $this->companyUserPermissionMaps[] = $permission;
        $permission->setAccount($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeCompanyUserPermissionMaps(AccountingBankPermission $permission): self
{
    if ($this->companyUserPermissionMaps->contains($permission)) {
        $this->companyUserPermissionMaps->removeElement($permission);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($permission->getAccount() === $this) {
            $permission->setAccount(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

relation table

```
Column(type="integer")

private $companyUserPermissionId;


/**
 * @var User
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="companyUserPermissionMaps")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="user_id", nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @var Company
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Company", inversedBy="companyUserPermissionMaps")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="company_id", nullable=true)
 */
private $company;


/**
 * @return int|null
 */
public function getCompanyUserPermissionId(): ?int
{
    return $this->companyUserPermisionId;
}



/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getUser(): ?User
{
    return $this->user;
}

/**
 * @param User $user
 * @return AccountingBankPermission
 */
public function setUser(?User $user): self
{
    $this->user = $user;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Company
 */
public function getCompany(): ?Company
{
    return $this->company;
}

/**
 * @param array $company
 * @return CompanyUserPermissionMap
 */
public function setCompany(?array $company): self
{
    $this->company = $company;
    return $this;
}
```

Form type

```
 $builder
            ->add('roles' ,ChoiceType::class ,[
                'required'  => true,
                'choices' => $this->roles,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'custom-control-label',
                ],
                'choice_attr' => function($val, $key, $index) {
                    return ['class' => 'custom-control-input'];
                },
                'attr'=>['class' =>'custom-checkbox custom-control']
            ])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'label' => "E-Mail"
            ])
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
                'label' => "First Name"
            ])
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class, [
                'label' => "Last Name"
            ])
            ->add('companyUserPermissionMaps' ,EntityType::class ,[
                'required' => true,
                'class'    => Company::class,
                'label'    => 'Compañia',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => false,
                'choice_label'  => 'legalName',
                'mapped'=>false
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => "Save"
            ])
```

and my controller function looks like this

```
 $user = new User();

    $originalRoles = $this->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles');

    $options=['roles' => $originalRoles ];

    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, $options);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $tempPassword = "some pass";

        $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword(
            $user,
            $tempPassword
        ));

        $companies=[];
        $companiesForm=$form->get('companyUserPermissionMaps')->getData();
        foreach ($companiesForm as $value) {
            $companies[] = $value->getCompanyId();
        }

        // Save object to database
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        /** @var CompanyRepository $companyRepository */
        $companyRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Company::class);
        $companiesArr =$companyRepository->findCompanyByArray($companies);
        $companyUserPermissionMap = new CompanyUserPermissionMap();
        $companyUserPermissionMap->setUser($user);
        $companyUserPermissionMap->setCompany($companiesArr);

        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->persist($companyUserPermissionMap);
```

Comment: is it normal in `User Entity` you have near `.. function addCompanyUserPermissionMaps(CompanyUserPermissionMaps $per...` `CompanyUserPermissionMaps` with an "s"? is it not `CompanyUserPermissionMap`?

Comment: yup you are right the thing is that i need to save multiple companies and asign them to 1 single user

Comment: Why not let doctrine handle the relation like here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional (substitute your Company Entity for  the Group Entity in the example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update**

Okay, so I neglected to mention the problem you're actually facing. The form component, smart as it is, will try to call getters and setters when loading/modifying the form data. Since your form contains `->add('companyUserPermissionMaps',...`, the form component will call `getCompanyUserPermissionMaps` on your entity (which will return a currently probably empty collection) and will try to write back to the entity via either `setCompanyUserPermissionMaps` or `add`/`remove` instead of `set`, if they are present.

Since your field actually behaves as if it holds a collection of `Company` objects, the setting of those on your `User` object will obviously fail with the error message you encountered:

> Expected value of type "App\Entity\CompanyUserPermissionMap" for association field "App\Entity\User#$companyUserPermissionMaps", got "App\Entity\Company" instead.

which absolutely makes sense. So, this problem can be fixed in different ways. The one way which you apparently already tried was setting `mapped` to `false`, but instead of `false` you used `'false'` (notice the quotes), which evaluates to true ... ironically. So to use your approach, you would have to remove the quotes. However, I propose a different approach, which I would much prefer!

**end update**

My general advice would be to hide stuff you don't want to show. So, in your form builder instead of

```
->add('companyUserPermissionMaps', EntityType::class, [
    'required' => true,
    'class'    => Company::class,
    'label'    => 'Compañia',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => false,
    'choice_label'  => 'legalName',
    'mapped'=>'false'
])
```

which obviously already is not a field that handles `CompanyUserPermissionMaps` but companies instead - so apparently you suspected this is semantically something different, you should go back to the `User` entity and give it a function `getCompanies` instead

```
public function getCompanies() {
    return array_map(function ($map) {
        return $map->getCompany();
    }, $this->getCompanyUserPermissionsMaps());
}
public function addCompany(Company $company) {
    foreach($this->companyUserPermissionMaps->toArray() as $map) {
        if($map->getCompany() === $company) {
            return;
        }
    }
    $new = new CompanyUserPermissionMap();
    $new->setCompany($company);
    $new->setUser($this);
    $this->companyUserPermissionMaps->add($new);
}
public function removeCompany(Company $company) {
    foreach($this->companyUserPermissionMaps as $map) {
        if($map->getCompany() == $company) {
            $this->companyUserPermissionMaps->removeElement($map);
        }
    }
}
```

you would then call the field `companies` (so `->add('companies', ...)`) and act on `Company` entities instead of those pesky maps. (I also don't really like exposing `ArrayCollection` and other internals to the outside. But hey, that's your decision.)

however, if your Maps are going to hold more values at some point, you actually have to work with the maps in your form, and not just with `Company` entities.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking time to answer this question Jakumi, the thing is that i need to  select multiple companies and asign it to this user, take a look a my controller function i just added that

Comment: @KevinLincon the form component recognizes collections and will automatically use `add[fieldname]` and `remove[fieldname]` if they are present, or `set[fieldname]s` (or properly pluralized form) on the entity to apply the changes done to the collection in the form component. That's probably why you get the error, because the form component actually tries to add companies (to the field you declared), but your entity doesn't support add Company as ...Map. your controller tries to circumvent the problem, but imho in an inefficient way.

Comment: @KevinLincon I just noticed a small detail causing your error, added it to the start of my answer ;o)

Comment: you were absolutely right, but the thing is i can't go throught inserting data, i updated what you told me and also the setCompany on the join table and still getting 
>> Expected value of type "App\Entity\Company" for association field "App\Entity\CompanyUserPermissionMap#$company", got "array" instead.

Comment: @KevinLincon that sounds very weird, have you adapted your controller code? because that would be necessary. Anyways, you should probably make a gist or something of how the code looks now, because it's unclear which changes you applied so far.

Comment: Just look at the relation table and the controller the Issue Is that i get an array of Companies and in the relation object when i use the setCompamy function causes the error

Comment: yeah ... that's why I asked, calling `$companyUserPermissionMap->setCompany($companiesArr)` is like ... confusing. why not loop through the companies and for each company you have to create and add a CompanyUserPermissionMap (you should check, if you have on of those). that's just one reason, I prefer my approach. the controller would be very clean then.

Comment: after some research i made it work with your solution, but when i try to edit the user relation and that means (unselecting from the input can't get it work )

Comment: @KevinLincon would you please upload some gist / code samples, because I obviously can't see what you did ;o)

Comment: this is the gist link https://gist.github.com/xLinconx/2d7789fffa220faffed80340252b2867

Comment: answered in your gist.

Comment: Thank you Jakum for your help

Comment: and answer added.